# Where can users in my domain find published Google Sites?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-sites

I created a Google site using the new Google sites. This site was then published with the setting "Published - Anyone at [organization] can find and view" selected. However, users who are not editors of the site cannot find it in Drive or on sites.google.com/new. Even when I explicitly share view permissions with a specific user that user still cannot find the site.

This issue is not isolated to this site, it appears to be the case with all sites. Currently users must either be editors to find sites or they must be sent the link.

Is there some sort of issue with Google's searching of Google sites? Otherwise, where can other users in my organization go to find the published site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google sites that are shared organization-wide can be found by users at cloudsearch.google.com. Note that site names are not searchable, only site contents.